# how to return all the fields of table2 based upon the occurrence of the id in the table1

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-order-by

I have 2 tables, one is table1

[image]

and another is table 2

[image]

I want the result by a query, like

[image]

I have tried select id from table2 order by (select id from table1); but it is giving error.

Comment: There's no order in a table, without a column to sort the data in table1 the expected way, it's impossible.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not images. (And those images are so big, I have to scroll to read a few rows of data.)

Comment: yes, sorry sir I will take of it from next time, and I am using mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got the answer

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join and sort. But you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows in `table1`. Let me assume that you have such column, and that is is called `ordering_id`.

```
select t2.*
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on t1.id = t2.id
order by t1.ordering_id
```

You can even use a subquery in the `order by` clause:

```
select *
from table2 t2
order by (select t1.ordering_id from table1 t1 where t1.id = t2.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables and then order the result.But for that you need to have some column for ordering and this does not seems to be the case. Syntax you are using for ordering will not work.

```
 SELECT A.ID, B.NAME FROM TABLE1 A INNER JOIN TABLE2 B
    ON(A.ID = B.ID) ORDER BY A.ID DESC
```

Comment: This is probably the answer I would have given, but it doesn't actually do what your question asked; if this is working for you, then you've asked the question poorly (which you have).

Comment: no, it is not giving the answer I just thought It will give.